# Small Angle Approximation in Lensing Equation

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, gravitational-lensing

In reading an article about gravitational lensing, I was pretty confused by the fact that the extra path travelled through the Lense compared with the direct path $OS$, in small angle approximation is given by $\mathbf{\alpha \xi }/ 2$, as asserted by the author. Where can I find a more detailed derivation of this result?
[image]

Reference:

Blandford, R., & Narayan, R. (n.d.). Fermat's principle, caustics, and the classification of gravitational lens images. NASA/ADS. Retrieved October 23, 2022, from https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1986ApJ...310..568B/abstract

Comment: Here in the last pages http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gr/one.pdf